# JWTEncodeFailureException: Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration

Tags: php, symfony, lexikjwtauthbundle

I found this error when I launch unit test in project symfony

> Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Exception\JWTEncodeFailureException: Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration.

application is working but in unit test I found this error, two keys public and private exist in config/jwt folder

.env.test:

```
KERNEL_CLASS='App\Kernel'
```

.env:

```
APP_SECRET=hello

###> lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=hellohello
###< lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ###
```

and when i add configurations lexikjwtauthentification in .env.test ,also error

Comment: What does the configuration look like?

Comment: @HansWurst I edit answer and I add configurations

Answer (score 1):

1. [Generate SSL keys](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/2.x/Resources/doc/index.rst#installation) for the UnitTest
2. Store the keys in a folder
3. Configure the keys in phpunit.xml.dist

Example from a exists project configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html -->
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="bin/.phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <php>
        <!-- Other config stuff -->
        
        <!-- ###+ lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ### -->
        <env name="JWT_SECRET_KEY" value="%kernel.project_dir%/tests/Fixtures/jwt/private.pem"/>
        <env name="JWT_PUBLIC_KEY" value="%kernel.project_dir%/tests/Fixtures/jwt/public.pem"/>
        <env name="JWT_PASSPHRASE" value="your-passphrase"/>
        <!-- ###- lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ### -->
        
        <!-- Other config stuff -->
    </php>
    <!-- Other config stuff -->
</phpunit>
```

```yaml
# config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    # Other config stuff
```

Comment: j'ai ajouté cette partie dans phpunit.dist.xml mais rien à changé

        <!-- ###+ lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ### -->
        <env name="JWT_SECRET_KEY" value="%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem"/>
        <env name="JWT_PUBLIC_KEY" value="%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem"/>
        <env name="JWT_PASSPHRASE" value="test"/>
        <!-- ###- lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle ### -->

Comment: I have written to you to generate new keys for the UnitTest. But you do not do this. This would exclude the possibility that something is wrong with the keys. You will now have to debug yourself. It doesn't have to be the keys. The exception is thrown here: https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/1305d7ec0ee540340d9041bd97659a13a0d1e6ed/Encoder/LcobucciJWTEncoder.php#L38